# Ruby String to Array method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

I've been searching and can't seem to find anything. I am using Easy-Roles & CanCan in a Rails app, and my roles column is defined as an array of string. When the user inputs/ selects a role from a dropdown list, the parameters gets sent as a string rather than an array, so I can't save it in the database.

Is there any method such that I can create an 1D-1 element string array from a string?

**EDIT:**

Here is my form:

```
<%= f.collection_select :roles, User::ROLES, :to_s, :split, 
                        :prompt=>"Select a role" %>
```

And I get this error:

```
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "Admin"
```

Comment: thank @Jeffrey very funny. Anyway, the reason I asked because if your attributes expect an array then perhaps your form should generate array (like `select` with `multiple=true`) for it right? If a user can only have 1 role at any given time then why use Easy-Roles at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not just

```
   [someString]
```

Where someString is a variable containing a string?

Or in your case:

```
  [params[:yourRoleString]]
```

Comment: How comes it doesn't try to interprete `:yourRoleString` as an index in `params`?

Answer (score -1):

You could just use

```
someString.split
```

that would do

```
someString = "Hello"
someString.split
  => ["Hello"]
```

Comment: Um, don't do this. `.split` is for breaking apart a string into an array: `"Hi There".split  #=> ["Hi", "There"]`. Not only will it be confusing to anyone else who reads your code, but if you have any spaces in the string it breaks it into pieces for you, which you probably don't want.